# trouble creating oval widgets in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having issues creating oval shapes on a canvas widget, so i have declared a canvas widget on a frame in the constructor.

```
class Map(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = none):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        .......  ##lines of code
        c = Canvas(master, width = 500,height = 500,relief = "groove")
        c.pack(side  = "right")

    def operation(self):
        .............. ##lines of code
        self.createoval()  ##call create oval method after loop code

    def createoval(self):
        x = 0
        y = 0
        c1 = canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+10, y+10, fill = "red")
        ##error map object has no create_oval.
        c1.coords(c1, x, y)  
        c1.move(c1, 500, 500)
        return c1
```

Ideally, what i would like is to create oval shapes after the loop has finished, so i would call the method that handles this, however i am having two issues.

1st. First issue i am having is creating oval on the canvas that has been established in the constructor. When i try to do this, i get message "canvas not defined" or when i use self.canvas.createoval, i get the message "map object has no attribute canvas"

So my question is how can i create a method that can create ovals on a canvas establsihed in the constructor?

2nd issue:

```
c1 = canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+10, y+10, fill = "red")
```

I get error that x is not defined, even though it is defined and i have used the coords() method but this has not fixed the problem.

Comment: Listen to the error messages. When you do `c = Canvas(...` that variable c only exists within the scope of the `init` method. It won't exist in `createoval` unless you make it a part of the object instance by saying `self.c`. What's more, you can't call it `c` in `init` but `canvas` in `createoval`. You need to use the same name for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of issues with this code. Below is code that works for me in creating an oval on your canvas (although given your coordinates, it is partly off screen).

```
from tkinter import *

class Map(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.c = Canvas(master, width = 500,height = 500,relief = "groove")
        self.c.pack(side  = "right")

    def operation(self):
        self.createoval()  ##call create oval method after loop code

    def createoval(self):
        x = 0
        y = 0
        c1 = self.c.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+10, y+10, fill = "red")
        return c1

m = Map(Tk())
m.createoval()
```

To address some of your problems:

1. You used `none` when you should have used `None`. It is case sensitive!
2. When you create an object, if you want a variable to be known to that instance of the object, you need to make it part of `self`. That means when you create your canvas with `c = Canvas(...` you need to actually have `self.c = Canvas(...`. Otherwise `c` will only exist within the scope of `__init__` and will not exist anywhere else.
3. You try to create your oval using the `canvas` variable but where did this variable come from? It was never defined previously. You specifically called your canvas variable `c` in the `__init__` method so you need to call it the same thing in the `createoval` method. Note you still also need to use `self.c`.
4. You used the line `c1.coords(c1,x,y)` presumably to set the position of the oval. However the creation of the oval will have already set the position, so if that was your intent, this is a redundant line. It is also not being used correctly. The variable `c1` that was created is a simple integer which is an ID for the oval on the canvas. You need to call the `coords` method with the canvas object using `self.c.coords(c1,x,y)`. This will reset the coordinates for the `c1` oval on the canvas `self.c` to the position `(x,y)`, however since you never changed `x` or `y` after creating the oval, it will set it to the same position and you won't notice any change.
5. You'll see the same problem with your call to `move` as you do for `coords`.